# How can access (read and write) system clipboard from a kernel module?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clipboard, kernel-module

I'm planning to implement a clipboard append functionality for some key combination for ubuntu and want it to work in all applications.
I think the best way to go is write a kernel module which does this.

Is there api which I can use to access system clipboard from kernel module?

Comment: on Linux, clipboard is a construct in user space, maintained/mediated  by the X11 server. You can not and should not write a kernel module to deal with this.

Comment: WHat do you actually mean by "system clipboard"? Linux is a multi user environment...

Comment: what is the alternative for implementing system wide clipboard append functionality then? daemon process or something?

Comment: Why does the normal clipboard application as present in whatever desktop environment you use not work for you? For me it allows to use key combinations and certainly works for all applications...

Comment: @arkascha are you telling me there is already a key combo to append to whatever already there on the clipboard??

Comment: @arkascha  By  "system clipboard" I meant for a single user, clipboard which all the applications use when you do ctrl+c? I understand that some apps like vim use their separate clipboard other than the common clipboard.

Comment: Ah, I begin to understand... You are referring not to the desktop environments clipboard application but to the internal selection the X server implements. You'd have to modify (or extend) that implementation then. As said: the X server, not the kernel, again since on a multi user environment several X servers can run in parallel. Maybe you can simply use the selection events raised somehow. I suggest you dive into the documentation of the X server...

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `xclip` utility. It implements CLI access to the X servers selection. I would expect you can implement some shell script invoked by a key combination writing a selection that way.

Comment: @arkascha I'll look into this. Thanks

Comment: Something like http://askubuntu.com/q/797132/158442? (I second the others, this doesn't belong in a kernel module)